# Rewrite request in subdirectory after rewriting into that subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following file structure in my server:

```
/
    source/             # source PHP files (not accessible)
    public/             # publicly accessible files (media)
        .htaccess       # second level htaccess to rewrite path into variable
        index.php       # request collector
    .htaccess           # first level htaccess to redirect flow into public dir
```

In first level htaccess I have rewrite rule moves flow into "public" directory.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!public/).*$ public/$0 [L,NC]
```

"public/.htaccess" contains following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if requesting existing file it is served. Otherwise request is rewrited like "example.com/namespace/controller/action?var=blah" to "example.com/index.php/namespace/controller/action?var=blah"

And that request should be handled by "public/index.php". However it seems that multiple rewriting is not allowed. Am I right? Or maybe I am making something wrong. I have to admit I can not understand mod_rewrite.

Comment: I don't understand why you have this condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !index.php`. I'm pretty sure you don't want it

Comment: To prevent redirect loop.

Comment: It seems that you are right - first RewriteCond (for existing files) does its job here. Thanks for this hint.

Comment: `QUERY_STRING` contains the part after `?`, in your case `index.php` will never be there. Maybe you'd want to use `REQUEST_URI` instead

Comment: Rule should be working fine, are you getting any problems?